# Azure hosted SQL: show all fields in a table as a saved View

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Probably a simple answer, but assume I have a table with 3 columns:

```
ab, cd, ef
```

I create a new view

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
```

It works. I save the view, SSMS automatically changes the saved version of the view to say:

```
SELECT dbo.tbl.ab, dbo.tbl.cd, dbo.tbl.ef
```

How do I keep the saved version of the view to include all columns in tbl rather than explicitly identifying each column?

Comment: You should not use `select *` in views, and preumably you're using the SSMS GUI tools? Just don't! Create your view in a query window as the actual `create view` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW vwTbl
AS
SELECT *
FROM tbl
```

Then you can query the view to retrieve all columns like:

```
SELECT * FROM vwTbl
```

Comment: Creating a view as a `select *` is not good advice. Any changes to the base table can cause it to blow up, you would also need `schema binding`

Comment: My response is based on the OP requirements and what he wants to accomplish. Sometimes people visiting this site is beginner user.